# Prove that $e^{i2a} - 1 = 2ie^{ia}\sin a$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

Here is my solution and I think I got a bit close but I literally have no idea how to continue from here

a is a real number. Just a note.

$2i(\cos(a) + i\sin(a))\sin(a)$

$2i(\cos(a)\sin(a) + i\sin^{2}(a))$

By using $\cos$ and $\sin$ identities:

$2i(\tfrac{\sin(2a)}{2} + i\sin^{2}(a))$

$i\sin(2a) -2\sin^{2}(a)$

Now...what? I don't have $\cos(2a)$ so I can't get "$e^{2ai}$" out and I have no idea how to get "-1" out too.

Any ideas?

Comment: player3236 gives a good hint for your method, but it was definitely easier to go left to right instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closer than you think. Recall the identity:

$$\cos (2a) = 1-2\sin^2 a$$

Comment: Woah. Couldn't believe I was this so damn close and then I stopped haha. Thank you so much for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct.
$i\sin 2a-2\sin^2 a$ = $i\sin 2a -(1-\cos 2a)$
= $i\sin 2a +\cos 2a -1$ = $e^{i2a}-1$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: since $e^{\pm ia}=\cos a\pm i\sin a$, $\sin a=\frac{e^{ia}-e^{-ia}}{2i}$.